# Microsoft query in Excel returning a blank column when SSMS does not

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms, ms-query, excel-import

I'm using MS query to return data to Excel from SSMS.

When I run the query in SSMS it runs without error and all fields return with records (see bottom left).
When I run the query in MS Query (to pull into Excel)  one of my fields is now returning blank records (see bottom right).
I thinking I have a conversion issue with the us.prod_qty field.  It's datatype is float and I'm trying to convert it to a string.

Thanks for any help with this.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty confident that query editor from 1998 (I do not jest) has no idea what a `nvarchar(MAX)` is (as they were added to SQL Server in 2005), and thus has no idea how to display it. The problem isn't the query, it's that the tool you are using hasn't seen any changes this millennium. You *could* try an `nvarchar(4000)`.

Comment: you might wanna look into moving onto a bit more modern solutions! There a lot of ways  of accessing sql server from excel